# Where do I get Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have never had Windows 7, and I would like it for my computer. Where do I get it?

Comment: Really????? Entering the search term "buy windows 7" into a search engine would have taken you less time than writing your post and registering?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Windows 7 is not available in "retail" packaging anymore (Feb 2015). You therefore have have two options left for obtaining Windows 7, assuming you specifically want Windows 7:

1. You can purchase a complete computer with Windows 7 pre-installed.
   (Windows 7 is still available to the OEM market).
2. You can purchase a complete computer with a Windows 8 license
   included. This will allow you to legally have your system
   "downgraded" to Windows 7. Note that a retail package of Windows 8
   DOES NOT include these downgrade rights. Read more here:
   http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=jyBs6WSOqCz

Alternatively, you can purchase a retail copy of Windows 8 in the flavour of your choice, and use Windows 8 instead.

Comment: Good answer, and to add more OP should note that Windows 10 is scheduled for 2015 release too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to buy it from a retailer.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy it from a retailer such as amazon or Bestbuy but you also have to consider
if you want windows 7 ultimate, professional, or home premium. You will probably want home premium because you are just using your computer for gaming.

Comment: Just curious where you got the gaming usage from.

Comment: In his original post it said he was going to use it for gaming

Comment: LOL, thought you were psychic.